# When using tf.data.TFRecordDataset as the input pipeline, how to have sess.run() or eval() invoked more than once in the same iteration round?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, dropout

With `tensorflow`, I've made a `dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)` and `iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()`. Then in each round `iterator.get_next()` would give out a mini-batch of data as input.

I am training a network with `Dropout` layer, so I'm supposed to write something like this:

```
sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={keep_prob:0.5})
accuracy,loss = sess.run([acc,loss],feed_dict={keep_prob:1.0})
```

in which `keep_prob` represents the probability to keep a neuron alive, that differs in training and testing (at this place is the evaluating) process.

The problem arises here is each `sess.run()` triggers the `iterator.get_next()` to get a new batch of input. This is not what it was supposed to be like.

What should I do if I wanna these two `sess.run()` have the same input tensors?

Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've just been guided to [this place](https://github.com/buptlj/learn_tf) where you could find the answer to this question.

The main idea is to use `tf.data.Iterator.from_structure()` instead of `tf.data.Dataset.make_initializable_iterator()` to create the iterator and to initialize the iterator for training, validation, and test dataset separately.

Comment: I found that `tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle()` is the more accurate answer here.